# Different time between equinoxes

Tags: orbital-motion, earth

I calculated from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinox) that there are 16 104 096 seconds between the vernal and autumnal equinox, if I made no mistake, this  is some 650 592 s longer than the other half orbit.

I imagine this is due  to the eccentricity of the orbit (0.0167) , can someone explain how these two values are related?

Can you tell me if my figure is exact ?